# How to ask for permissions in MiUi pre - Marshmallow?

Tags: android

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

Log.d(TAG, permissionCheck + "");
```

The permission check always returns PERMISSION_GRANTED but in the OS (MiUi) the app doesn't have permissions.

Test Device : Redmi Note 3 Pro (MIUI 8)

Comment: So, do not use it.

Comment: try this for checking [permission](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39263191/3960700)

Comment: look at my code

Comment: Im trying it out @Vyacheslav, will get back to you

Comment: @SachetBajracharya , updated a bit

Comment: @SachetBajracharya , have you solved this problem?

Comment: @Vyacheslav no I haven't. Its only an issue in Xiaomi Phones with MiUI.

Comment: I faced same issue i have an app in which user sends sms, if i denied permission it return 0 but if i accept permission still return 0 . and i doesn't  find any solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

in miui you need to ask permissions in different way.You need to check permission mode is equal to zero or not.
check this function for read sms permission in above marshmallow

```
private boolean checkUsagePermission() {
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
    int mode = 0;
    mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow("android:read_sms", android.os.Process.myUid(), getPackageName());
    boolean granted = mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;
    if (!granted) {
        //write your code for accept that permission
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

once you look at AppOpsManager class in your  android studio.

Answer (score 0):

For some permissions i'm using such approach:

```
private boolean permissionsActivated = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M);

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//....
        requirepermissionsifneeded();
//....
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void requirepermissionsifneeded() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (!canAll()) {
                    permissionsActivated = false;
                    requestPermissions(INITIAL_PERMS, REQUESTPERM);
                } 

else {
permissionsActivated = true;
}
            } else {
                permissionsActivated = true;
            }
        }


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private boolean hasPermission(String perm) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == checkSelfPermission(perm));
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        }
private boolean canAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (canAccessLocation() && canCoarseLocation() && canGetAccounts());
    }
    private boolean canAccessLocation() {
        return hasPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    private boolean canCoarseLocation() {
        return hasPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
    private boolean canGetAccounts() {
        return hasPermission(android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUESTPERM: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    permissionsActivated = true;
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, ":(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    permissionsActivated = false;
                }
            return;
            }
            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```

Somewhere in code

`permissionsActivated = canAll();`

Answer (score -2):

For below API 23, we usually assume that our app will have all permissions declared in the Manifest, Xiaomi being one of the exceptions.

What you could do is place your code in a try catch block and see if you can identify the scenario using the exception thrown.

I don't have such a device so cannot test this. My guess is it will throw a `SecurityException`.

For receive SMS permission though, i don't think you can do this. Instead, inform the user on installation to not to disable permissions. Or you could ask user to make it the default sms app.

Do try it out and let us know!

Comment: @PrinceChampappilly what exactly doesn't work? Did you check the MiUi permissions app to enable the access?

Comment: He is asking about programatically invoking the RECIEVE_SMS permission request or for auto granting it on install for MIUI, your approach works only on non MIUI phones. READ_CONTACTS is fine , but RECIEVE_SMS and READ_SMS cannot be programatically requested, because Most AUTO GENERATED messages are marked as SERVICE_SMS by MIUI and that permission is not granted to APPS. Any Permission can be granted from the Security page or the APP Permission Page.

Comment: Yes i missed the sms permission before. It looks like this was something Xiaomi used to do in older devices below API 23. From 23 onward things have improved.